# Failed to find module: "@angular/router/common_router_providers" error with angular router upgrade

Tags: angularjs, angular, nativescript

I am trying to upgrade my nativescript application to use the new Angular Router, however, I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.tns.NativeScriptApplication: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "@angular/router/common_router_providers", relative to: /app/tns_modules/
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4710)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Failed to find module: "@angular/router/common_router_providers", relative to: /app/tns_modules/
    at com.tns.Module.resolvePathHelper(Module.java:220)
    at com.tns.Module.resolvePath(Module.
```

in my `main.ts` I have:

```
import {nativeScriptBootstrap} from "nativescript-angular/application";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import {APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "./app.routes";

nativeScriptBootstrap(AppComponent, [APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS]);
```

then in my `app.routes.ts` I have:

```
import {RouterConfig} from '@angular/router';
import {nsProvideRouter} from "nativescript-angular/router";
import {HomePage} from "./Components/Home/home.component";
import {Bottles} from "./Components/BottleList/bottleList.component";

const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "/home", terminal: true },
    { path: "home", component: HomePage },
    { path: "bottles", component: Bottles },
];

export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    nsProvideRouter(routes, {enableTracing: false })
];
```

then my `app.component.ts`:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from "nativescript-angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: "main",
  directives: [NS_ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  template: "<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>"
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  page: Page;
}
```

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

### Update:

I am using -

- tns-android: **2.1.1**
- @angular/common: **2.0.0-rc.4**
- @angular/router: **3.0.0-beta.2**
- nativescript-angular: **0.2.0**
- tns-core-modules: **2.1.0**
- nativescript (global): **2.1.1**
- node (global): **4.4.7**

Comment: Did I see correctly that you got this resolved via GitHub or Slack? Was this an issue with a conflict or some missing API's in the latest router with Angular rc4?

Comment: @HK1 nope, I am still facing this... The issue I saw says they resolved it be using a previous version of the router but that hasn't worked for me...

Comment: Can you post which versions of tns, angular, and angular router your project uses? Maybe just post the whole contents of your packages.json file.

Comment: @HK1 Sure, please see above (my package.json file is pretty long, so I only added the bits I think are relevant). All other angular bits are `-rc.4` and   I tried using `@angular/router@3.0.0-alpha.7`but I got the same result ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something but it's only a workaround : by using all the rc3 version of the angular2 component (except router (3.0.0-alpha.7) and router-deprecated (2.0.0-rc.2)), it works. But you need to add some changes in your files too (check [here](https://github.com/ngydat/connect))

Comment: You shouldn't necessarily have to use Router Deprecated. The new router 3.0.0.0-alpha.7 does work with Angular rc3 though I believe there could be some bugs. I have it working, but had a hard time making it work and am still not sure why it works now or didn't work earlier and also am not doing anything very advanced with it. The router part of NativeScript w/Angular2 is pretty buggy, but they need guys like us using it and reporting the bugs and complaints on GitHub and Slack so they can make it stable.

Comment: @HK1 Do you think we can remove router-deprecated from package.json ?

Comment: I didn't bother to remove it, I just didn't use it in the import statements on my .ts files. But if you're not using it, I think it would be safe to remove. It seems that NativeScript versions roughly coincide with specific versions of Angular and Angular Router, each with their own bugs, but there's little to no documentation on this. So it's anyone's guess as to which versions of the Angular and Angular Router and TNS you can mix and use.

Answer (score 1):

I did upgrade last week to `@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7` from    `@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2` and it went successfully.

Take a look at this **NativeScript/sample-Groceries** branch  https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/tree/angular-v3-router it has the rc3 upgrade commits.

Also removing **platforms** & **tns_modules** folders and upgrading (remove and install) **tns** globally might fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Having exactly the same behavior. The only workaround to the moment seems to be leaving `@angular/router` at version 3.0.0-alpha.7